# Prediction intervals using predict.polr vs predict

Tags: r, prediction-interval, ordered-logit, polr

I am a little puzzled by this - hope you will give this a shot!

I am looking for a way to get prediction intervals from an ordered logit model (`polr()`).

The regression I am using is:

reg<-polr(satisfaction~ X1 + C2 + C3,...), where X1 is continuous and C2&3 are categorical variables with 2 and 5 categories respectively.

The code I am using at present to get the prediction values is `predict()` from the *stats* package. It works to an extent - I have the predicted probabilities. But I can't use it for prediction interval. When I use "intervals = prediction/predict", it doesn't work.

So I have taken to using the glm.predict package, with the `basepredict.polr` function. Its usage description says the following:

basepredict(model, values, sim.count=1000, conf.int=0.95, sigma=NULL, set.seed=NULL,
type = c("any", "simulation", "bootstrap"), summary = TRUE).

My code for the above at present is

`basepredict.polr(reg, c(17,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),...)`, where 17 is for X1 I would like to predict at and the others are the underlying values for the subsequent categories. For example, the first '2' is actually a "Yes" respone to the C2. I have made sure to keep the values in the order they appear in the coefficient section of the regression ouput.

If I dont apply the underlying values and use the labels instead, I get the following error

> Type not specified: Using simulation as n >= 500 Error in beta_draw
> %*% x :    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

When I do use the underlying values, I get wildly different mean prediction probability to the ones I get under the `predict` function. I do get the prediction interval I am looking for, but it seems to span from nearly 0 (at 2.5%) and nearly 1 (at 07.5%) confidence interval.

Prediction Probabilities using `predict`:
Sat: 0.8
Neither:0.13
Dissat: 0.07

Prediction probabilities using `basepredict.polr`
Sat: 0.1
Neither:0.05
Dissat: 0.85

I was wondering if someone knew how to solve this puzzle? What makes this even more interesting is that when I drop C2&3, the probabilities seem to be broadly similar, but inclusion of additional variable seems to throw it off.

I would really appreciate your help.